# Dynamcially referencing an component attribute in default attribute of type="object[]"

Tags: aura-attribute, default-value

What is the correct way to default another attributes when declaring object[]?

This:

```
<aura:attribute name="foo" type="object[]" 
      default="[
        {
          'title': 'Account Name',
          'value': {!v.Account.Name}
        },
        {
          'title': 'Contact Email',
          'value': {!v.Contact.Name}
        }
      ]"/>
```

Or this:

```
<aura:attribute name="foo" type="object[]" 
      default="{![
        {
          'title': 'Account Name',
          'value': v.Account.Name
        },
        {
          'title': 'Contact Email',
          'value': v.Contact.Name
        }
      ]}"/>
```

Won't compile with error `Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}`

This will compile but will won't get parsed at runtime:

```
<aura:attribute name="foo" type="object[]" 
      default="[
        {
          'title': 'Account Name',
          'value': v.Account.Name
        },
        {
          'title': 'Contact Email',
          'value': v.Contact.Name
        }
      ]"/>
```

Of course it works fine with statis references:

```
<aura:attribute name="foo" type="object[]" 
          default="[
            {
              'title': 'Account Name',
              'value': 'Buzz'
            },
            {
              'title': 'Contact Email',
              'value': 'foo@baz.qux'
            }
          ]"/>
```

I can always do this via JS on init, but I would rather not to.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this. I am in same situation...

Comment: @user28452 sorry no, ended up using different pattern in the app. Still, would be useful to know.

Comment: Here is the answer from the community that I received and it worked!                   https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200106/default-value-for-an-attribute-of-type-object?noredirect=1#comment302436_200106